# Why would C have "fake arrays"?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm reading [*The Unix haters handbook*](http://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf) and in chapter 9 there's something I don't really understand:

> C doesn’t really have arrays either. It has something that looks like an array
>   but is really a pointer to a memory location.

I can't really imagine any way to store an array in memory other than using pointers to index memory locations. How C implements "fake" arrays, anyways? Is there any veracity on this claim?

Comment: It's hard to speak for the author of the book, maybe they wanted more safe arrays, with size and bounds checking.

Comment: What a load of hogwash. Of course c has arrays; and most variables have a location in memory.. it's just that you can use pointer arithmetic to access array elements, that's all.

Comment: I think the author was just trying to be snarky and didn't expect anyone to question it.

Comment: Really I think the author is a bit of a turkey.

Comment: Possibly a bit broad as a question. Other languages effectively keep shape information about the array in a structure so that the language runtime knows things like number of dimensions, lower and upper bounds of each dimension of the array and anything else that's needed, as well as the pointer to the start of the data storing the array.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia says that the book is: *"[...]a semi-humorous edited compilation of messages to the Unix-Haters mailing list."*

Comment: The UNIX-HATERS Handbook is an interesting read. It was published in 1994.  It describes an era before the POSIX standards helped unify the way Unix systems behaved. A lot of what it complains about is fixed. But there was also some justice to many of the complaints.

Comment: Like me. I don't have arrays, but I could really use a raise. But seriously, what would be a true array in a programming language? It's just an implementation after all.  It's not "just" a pointer to memory, it's *also* a pointer. It's something you can use as an array *and* as a pointer to memory. In and of itself that sentence seems kind of meaningless without clarification of how C's array implementation differs from what he means by "arrays".

Comment: It's not so much that C arrays aren't "true" arrays, as it is that C's simplistic type and memory systems make it _much_ more efficient to operate on any given array in terms of a pointer to its first element, instead of on the array as a whole.  So, since efficiency is one of C's primary design factors, arrays are designed to automatically discard their type information and act as that pointer whenever the type information isn't explicitly required.

Comment: This book was published by the same people who publish the "…For Dummies" series of books. Draw your own conclusions about its technical accuracy. Unless you're reading for sheer entertainment value, perhaps you should consider not wasting your time.

Comment: UNIX-HATERS is a work of humor, not a teaching material. It's the kind of humor that's *rooted* in fact, but that doesn't mean you should take anything in it at face value.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the author’s point is that C arrays are really just a thin veneer on pointer arithmetic. The subscript operator is defined simply as `a[b] == *(a + b)`, so you can easily say `5[a]` instead of `a[5]` and do other horrible things like access the array past the last index.

Comparing to that, a “true array” would be one that knows its own size, doesn’t let you do pointer arithmetic, access past the last index without an error, or access its contents using a different item type. In other words, a “true array” is a tight abstraction that doesn’t tie you to a single representation – it could be a linked list instead, for example.

PS. To spare myself some trouble: I don’t really have an opinion on this, I’m just explaining the quote from the book.

Comment: Hmm, so arrays are permitted to have O(n) item access and still be called arrays? That rankles a tad.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Where did you get `O(n)` from?

Comment: @Alexander Linked List.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Oh, I missed that. The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) mentions linked lists: "Array types are often implemented by array structures; however, in some languages they may be implemented by hash tables, linked lists, search trees, or other data structures."

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish In any case, when I see "linked list", I read "cache miss and performance terror" and run far far away

Comment: I don’t know much about the internal representation of arrays in popular languages, the linked list was just an example (and maybe not the best one). You can replace it with something that makes more sense – copy on write, maybe? Main point is that having the definition of an array type directly tied to a particular low-level representation has a lot of downsides.

Comment: This answer is wrong on any number of levels. An array in C ***does*** know its own size. Why would it restrict you from doing pointer arithmetic? C doesn't restrict you from doing pointer arithmetic on any pointer if you want to; the language is designed with the philosophy that you know what you're doing and you should be allowed to do it. And the claim that an array can be implemented as a linked list is a lot of nonsense, as has already been pointed out. If there's a language that does it, it certainly wouldn't be the performance-minded C!

Comment: About the only thing you've got right here is the first sentence. Yes, the author is probably trying to say that C arrays are little more than a thin veneer on pointer arithmetic. But so are lots of things in C, so more explanation is needed. That doesn't mean arrays aren't a true first-class entity in the language—they are. Beginners often confuse arrays and pointers, and the language in many cases seems to blur them together, but they are different. What you're saying about the subscript operator has nothing in particular to do with arrays; it is just the formal syntax of the [] operator.

Comment: You *do* have strong feelings for C :–) We obviously disagree, I’m happy to leave it at that. Just a single thing: does an array really know its size in C? What if I get a dynamically allocated array from a function, can the array tell me its size somehow?

Comment: @zoul C99's VLAs do know their sizes, i.e. `size_t size=get_size();int array[size];printf("%zu\n",sizeof array);` will print value of `size*sizeof(int)`. And even before C99, the static-length arrays similarly do know their size.

Comment: But dynamically allocated arrays don’t, do they?

Comment: @zoul VLA is _variable-length array_. Dynamically-allocated (i.e. `malloc`'ed) chunks of memory aren't C arrays. They are just chunks of memory you have pointers to.

Comment: Well, I think that’s basically what the original quote is about. What if I want to return an array from a function, for example?

Comment: You can't do it directly. Either use a struct with a statically-sized array, or you can only return a pointer. Note that these options result in different storage for the data and different lifetime of the storage.

Comment: Exactly! And that’s why I understand if someone doesn’t consider arrays to be a real first-class citizen type in C.

Answer (score 13):

There is a difference between C arrays and pointers, and it can be seen by the output of `sizeof()` expressions. For example:

```
void sample1(const char * ptr)
{
   /* s1 depends on pointer size of architecture */
   size_t s1 = sizeof(ptr); 
}
size_t sample2(const char arr[])
{
   /* s2 also depends on pointer size of architecture, because arr decays to pointer */
   size_t s2 = sizeof(arr); 
   return s2;
}
void sample3(void)
{
   const char arr[3];
   /* s3 = 3 * sizeof(char) = 3 */
   size_t s2 = sizeof(arr); 
}
void sample4(void)
{
   const char arr[3];
   /* s4 = output of sample2(arr) which... depends on pointer size of architecture, because arr decays to pointer */
   size_t s4 = sample2(arr); 
}
```

The `sample2` and `sample4` in particular is probably why people tend to conflate C arrays with C pointers, because in other languages you can simply pass arrays as an argument to a function and have it work 'just the same' as it did in the caller function. Similarly because of how C works you can pass pointers instead of arrays and this is 'valid', whereas in other languages with a clearer distinction between arrays and pointers it would not be.

You could also view the `sizeof()` output as a consequence of C's pass-by-value semantics (since C arrays decay to pointers).

Also, some compilers also support this C syntax:

```
void foo(const char arr[static 2])
{
   /* arr must be **at least** 2 elements in size, cannot pass NULL */
}
```

Comment: The syntax of the latter is standard C. Yet not well known and even less often understood.

Comment: @Olaf I know but between the the age of the *Unix-haters' handbook* and the lack of support for modern C in general by some (strangely) popular C-compilers (`msvc`) I felt it best not to dwell too much on the issue here...

Comment: Luckily typical Unix compilers like gcc and clang do not insist sticking with an since 18 years outdated version of the standard. So we should presume for a Unix question modern C is available (and also to push eventually getting rid of those legacies).

Comment: @Olaf Interesting. While the syntax is understood by ``gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra``, it doesn’t seem to complain when I pass a ``const char buf[2]`` or ``0`` to a function with ``const char buf[static 4]``. What am I missing? Update: ``clang -std=c11`` does warn :/

Comment: @JonasWielicki apparently it's not enforced, as in _passing anything not satisfying these criteria has undefined behavior_. Otherwise you couldn't e.g. `malloc` two bytes and pass the pointer to such a function.

Comment: @Ruslan Of course, I can cast to tell the compiler that I’m sure I’m doing the right thing.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: Can you provide a reference to the standard requiring a a diagnostic for this? Oherwise it's not clear what your point is, apparently both compliers know this declarator, which is all my comment implied. (don't confuse compiler warnings for **potentially/likely** problematic code with required warnings. The latter shall be active by default and result in an error, not a warning. And you did not say which gcc version. They often add warnings with new releases. Also gcc and clang might require different options to get the same set of warnings - if at all).

Comment: @Olaf it is apparently a bug in GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50584

Comment: @user268396: As Jonas did not, maybe you can provide the reference where the standard **requires** such a diagnostics. Until then, it is not a bug with respect to standard compliance, but might be a planned (indeed useful) feature. Note that such a warning cannot provide a guarantee, as you loose the size information with the first function call already, because a parameter `int i[static 2]` still is a **pointer**, not an array! Thus the keyword has **very** limited usage. Better pass a VLA and `assert` the length at run-time.

Comment: @Olaf You are right – I just had the hope that I was missing something else. I never wanted to imply that the standard required anything. I edited my comment several times, but I could not un-do the ping I gave you when I found out that this is a GCC-specific issue.

Comment: Example 2 is wrong. Parameter arr doesn't decay to a pointer, it is a pointer.

Answer (score 12):

The statement you quoted is factually incorrect. Arrays in C are not pointers.

The idea of implementing arrays as pointers was used in B and BCPL languages (ancestors of C), but it has not survived transition to C. At the early ages of C the "backward compatibility" with B and BCPL was considered somewhat important, which is why C arrays closely *emulate* behavior of B and BCPL arrays (i.e. C arrays easily "decay" to pointers). Nevertheless, C arrays are not "pointers to a memory location".

The book quote is completely bogus. This misconception is rather widespread among C newbies. But how it managed to get into a book is beyond me.

Comment: You missed the context of what the book is. It's an epic act of trolling, not a serious book aimed at teaching factually correct things about C and Unix.

Answer (score 8):

Author probably means, that arrays are constrained in ways which make them feel like 2nd class citizens from programmer point of view. For example, two functions, one is ok, another is not:

```
int finefunction() {
    int ret = 5;
    return ret;
}

int[] wtffunction() {
    int ret[1] = { 5 };
    return ret;
}
```

You can work around this a bit by wrapping arrays in structs, but it just sort of emphasizes that arrays are different, they're not like other types.

```
struct int1 {
    int a[1];
}

int[] finefunction2() {
    struct int1 ret = { { 5 } };
    return ret;
}
```

Another effect of this is, that you can't get size of array at runtime:

```
int my_sizeof(int a[]) {
    int size = sizeof(a);
    return size;
}

int main() {
    int arr[5];
    // prints 20 4, not 20 20 as it would if arrays were 1st class things
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(arr), my_sizeof(arr)); 
}
```

Another way to say what the authors says is, in C (and C++) terminology, "array" means something else than in most other languages.

---

So, your title question, how would a "true array" be stored in memory. Well, there is no one single kind of "true array". If you wanted true arrays in C, you have basically two options:

1. Use calloc to allocate buffer, and store pointer and item count here

   ```
   struct intarrayref {
     size_t count;
     int *data;
   }
   ```

   This struct is basically reference to array, and you can pass it around nicely to functions etc. You will want to write functions to operate on it, such as create copy of the actual data.
2. Use [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), and allocate whole struct with single calloc

   ```
   struct intarrayobject {
       size_t count;
       int data[];
   }
   ```

In this case, you allocate both the metadata (`count`), and the space for array data in one go, but the price is, you can't pass this struct around as value any more, because that would leave behind the extra data. You have to pass pointer to this struct to functions etc. So it is matter of opinion whether one would consider this a "true array" or just slightly enhanced normal C array.

Comment: Arrays _are_ "first-class things" in C, it's just that they are highly constrained after-the-fact.

Comment: There is no syntax to return array from function. It is not possible to assign array. Doesn't sound very first class to me.

Comment: @hyde - The same is true for arrays in many other languages, e.g. Pascal.   But nobody complains about Pascal not having first-class arrays.  The simple fact that while arrays in C are a little odd (largely due to the fact that when used in many circumstances they are automatically converted to pointers) they aren't equivalent to pointers, a point which the author of the quoted book seems to have neglected.

Comment: @hyde: That comes under the "constraints" category. An array is defined as a first class type, period.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I changed the wording a bit to avoid terminology ambiguity.

Answer (score 7):

Like the entire book, it's a case of trolling, specifically, the type of trolling that involves stating something almost-true but wrong to solicit angry responses about why it's wrong. C most certainly does have actual arrays/array types, as evidenced by the way pointer-to-array types (and multi-dimensional arrays) work.

Comment: There's a fine line, and traditionally (especially at the time the book was written) trolling meant something intended to be comical and playful, much like satire. It was only much later that the word got reappropriated as a euphemism for harassment, hate speech, etc.